# Build Cyrus SASL as static library on Windows

Tags: static, static-libraries, sasl

I need the library Cyrus SASL as a static library on Windows (https://cyrusimap.org/mediawiki/index.php/Downloads#SASL_Library)

How to do that ?

Comment: Don't use SASL. It is AGPL meaning your app also becomes AGPL. Even if you run it on the server, you must publish all your source code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you will need a MinGW and MSYS environment and then just build the SASL from sources like it were on Unix-like, i. e.

```
./configure
make
make install
```

You will get some *.a files -- those are static libraries, built with MinGW, they should work for Windows.
I'm still checking this topic, so I'll add some more info if I'm done with it.

For more reference about building projects from sources check the `INSTALL` file in your project's root directory, i. e. `cyrus-sasl-<version>/INSTALL`

*upd:* this seems to be not an easy thing to do, check out this [article](http://blog.chinaunix.net/uid-9935135-id-181735.html)

*upd2:* if you prefer Visual Studio, you could check this rather outdated [howto](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/cyrus2/windows.html).

*upd3:* in general good [article](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/manual/html_node/Installing-under-Windows.html) from GNU